# Sign an electron app on macos using pfx certificate

Tags: macos, electron, code-signing

I have created an electron app. Now I want to sign code for both windows and mac platform. But I have only go daday pfx certificate.I successfully signed code using pfx certificate from go daday in windows platform. So,Can I sign an electron app on macos platform using go daday certificate?

Answer (score 3):

You *can* sign a macOS app with a GoDaddy code-signing certificate, but it probably won't do what you want. Here's what [Apple's developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html) says (with my emphasis added):

> Note: Apple uses the industry-standard form and format of code signing
>   certificates. Therefore, if your company already has a third-party
>   signing identity that you use to sign code on other systems, you can
>   use it with the macOS codesign command. Similarly, if your company is
>   a certificate issuing authority, contact your IT department to find
>   out how to get a signing certificate issued by your company. **However,
>   while these valid certificates allow you to sign your code, you can
>   only distribute through the App Store or through the Developer ID
>   program when you sign with a certificate issued by Apple.**

So, the question is: how is your application going to be distributed to users' computers?

- If it's sold through Apple's App Store, you need to [become an Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/programs/), get a Mac App Distribution certificate from Apple, and sign the app with that before submitting it to Apple.
- If it's distributed outside Apple's App Store (e.g. via web download), then you *also* need to become an Apple developer, get a Developer ID certificate, and use *that* to sign it. If you don't sign it with the right kind of certificate, [Gatekeeper](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491) will prevent users from opening the app unless they go through a special procedure to trust the app.

Either way, you need to join the Apple Developer program, and use an Apple-issued code signing certificate to sign the macOS version of your app.